# Xamarin Custom Map Pin Renderers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Firstly I would like to disclose that I am a new developer and just starting out coding with Xamarin and C sharp.

Ok. So I am creating a custom renderer for the map pin in my application. I have been using the following sample code found here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin

As it currently stands I am trying to set the popup on the pins so that when I click on them they will either go to a page in the app or possibly have a popup come up with more details on that specific pin location. Currently when I click on the pin popup it takes me to a website.

Here is a screen shot of the app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIqH4.png)

I have been looking at this code and Im trying to figure out if it would be possible to change the URL to a local page?

```
  InitializeComponent();

        var position1 = new Position(52.649005, -7.250712);
        var position2 = new Position(52.648061, -7.252879);
        var position3 = new Position(52.650519, -7.249260);
        var position4 = new Position(52.652680, -7.244724);
        var position5 = new Position(52.648061, -7.252879);
        var position6 = new Position(52.648061, -7.252879);

        var pin1 = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position1,
            Label = "Butler House",
            Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
            Id = "test",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
        };

        var pin2 = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position2,
            Label = "Talbots Tower",
            Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
            Id = "",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"

        };
```

In the CustomMapRender.cs file here is where I believe I need to be able to alter the CustomPin.URL to allow me to click and get local pages in the app itself.

```
 protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Id.ToString());
        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Id.ToString());
            annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin-red-10.png"); //pin is set by image not changable by colour attributes
            annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Ireland-icon.png"));
            annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Id = customPin.Id.ToString();
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
        }
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
```

Any help or insight on this would be much appreciated as Im going around in circles trying so many different things at present.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

GetViewForAnnotation method is for getting the **MKAnnotationView** (i.e., the callout that's displaying the details of the Pin).

What you need is the tap event of the MKMapView callout. Add an EventHandler to **CalloutAccessoryControlTapped** and handle the logic for navigation.

In the sample provided it would be [this part](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/88cdcf8ae781a31c8906c1cd9e81e813303f19ef/CustomRenderers/Map/Pin/iOS/CustomMapRenderer.cs#L76)

```
void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            // handle navigation here instead of opening the webpage
            var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customView.Url))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(customView.Url));
            }
        }
```